# How to unit test outside of main.rs?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I'm new to Rust, I have a file structure like this

- main.rs
- chip8.rs
- chip8_gui.rs

I added a unit test in main.rs and a unit test in chip8.rs (a simple `assert_eq!(2,2)`) but it only finds the test in main.rs. Why? I am trying to test a private function of chip8.rs.

Comment: Refer to https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out TDD is fun, but you have to make sure it compiles! The solution was simply to add `mod chip8` in `main.rs`